# divs overlap paragraph text

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="position:absolute;float:left;top:0;left:0;width:50px;">57</div>
        <div style="width:550px;position:absolute;float:left;top:0;left:50px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed ipsum eu justo ornare euismod. Suspendisse bibendum venenatis nisl, ut blandit odio aliquet sit amet. Donec ultricies purus eu metus faucibus venenatis. Donec imperdiet sagittis pretium. Quisque pellentesque malesuada eros sit amet fringilla. Cras egestas vehicula pharetra. Nunc mattis aliquam erat pharetra tempus. Sed magna dui, facilisis nec pharetra dignissim, lobortis vel nulla. Etiam tellus dui, dapibus sit amet sodales vitae, tempus eu felis. Nam interdum sagittis libero, nec sagittis nisl dapibus et. Nulla facilisi.</div>
    </div><br /><br />

    <p style="margin-left:50px;">This is my paragraph</p>
</div>
```

As you can see from [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tSYvB/), My Lorem Ipsum text overlaps with my paragraph. I tried putting somme `<br />` between my div and my paragraph, but they still overlap. I want my paragraph to appear after my text. Any help please?

Thank you

Comment: position absolute? with float? mmmmm dirty marup + CSS

Comment: Absolute positioning and floating don't usually go together.

Comment: It's not good to use position absolute with float?

Comment: Yargh, you will need to rework your CSS.  Why not make a style sheet instead of making all of your styles in-line? Because you have `position:absolute`, that element has no substance at that point.  You will need to give it a height and width

Answer (score 0):

You don't use position:absolute with a float. You can just use the float in this case and get rid of position and the related css.
Just this would be fine:

```
<div>
    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="float:left;width:50px;">57</div>
        <div style="width:550px;float:left;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed ipsum eu justo ornare euismod. Suspendisse bibendum venenatis nisl, ut blandit odio aliquet sit amet. Donec ultricies purus eu metus faucibus venenatis. Donec imperdiet sagittis pretium. Quisque pellentesque malesuada eros sit amet fringilla. Cras egestas vehicula pharetra. Nunc mattis aliquam erat pharetra tempus. Sed magna dui, facilisis nec pharetra dignissim, lobortis vel nulla. Etiam tellus dui, dapibus sit amet sodales vitae, tempus eu felis. Nam interdum sagittis libero, nec sagittis nisl dapibus et. Nulla facilisi.</div>
    </div><br /><br />

    <p style="margin-left:50px;">This is my paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Though, as the comments suggest - you should put this in a stylesheet and avoid inline declarations. It's cleaner and tends to be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your position absolute **and** put `clear: both` to your paragraph to reset the floating elements

```
<div>
        <div style="position:relative;">
            <div style="float:left;width:40px;">57</div>
            <div style="width:550px;float:left;left:40px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed ipsum eu justo ornare euismod. Suspendisse bibendum venenatis nisl, ut blandit odio aliquet sit amet. Donec ultricies purus eu metus faucibus venenatis. Donec im.</div>
        </div>

        <p style="clear: both;margin-left:40px">This is my paragraph</p>
</div>
```

[Live exemple here](http://jsfiddle.net/fgTMG/)

Comment: the "57" is no longer in line with the top of the lorem ipsum text.

Comment: @ZackT. Witch browser are you using ? did you check my link ? It works well on latest chrome ...

Comment: I did check your link. The layout looks like this http://postimg.org/gallery/2sr6q6xo/26187e81/ The 57 is sitting ON TOP of the lorem ipsum instead of beside it like in the OP's post.

Comment: You are absolutely right that's because of the width of the div holding the lorem ipsum content. Trie to reduce it or putting it into % insted of px

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got the unholy duo of absolute positioning and float:left without a "clear". This means your first child div with those two children will have no height whatsoever. I recommend removing position:absolute and float:left from these divs, using instead:

```
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
```

This will allow them to flow left -> right and have a height within the page flow.

Comment: I wanna avoid using inline-block because that causes problem in IE

Answer (score 0):

If you are using floats why are you mixing it with absolute positions?

I've changed this a little.

```
<div style="float:left;width:40px;">57</div>
        <div style="width:550px;float:left;margin-left:40px;">
```

Try this one. By the way, I've added clearfix method too, as it is recommended to clear floating spaces when you are not floating anything anymore.

If you don't want them, you can remove the div with .clearfix and the CSS.

**[Here you go.](http://jsfiddle.net/tSYvB/3/)**

Comment: I want my paragraph to appear at the bottom of my Lorem Ipsum text and I wanna have a blank line between them

Comment: Have you seen the code link I've posted? // EDIT: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/tSYvB/9/ Btw, expand the preview container on JSFiddle or the width you specified will always wrap your paragraph along the container size, as it doesn't have enough size as long the one you specified.